# Total number of possible binary operations .

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

If there are n elements in a set the number of binary operations that can be defined are 2n, am I right or wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

If the definition of "operation" is any function $\oplus \colon A \times A \to A$ without any further restrictions, there are $n^2$ values of the function a define independently among $n$ values, so it is $n^{n^2}$.

Comment: It can be also seen as the number of ways to fill an $n^2$-tuple where each position assumes $n$ values.

$\underbrace{(\_\ \_\ \_ \ \_ \dots \_ \ \_)}_{n^2\ positions}$ So it is $n^{n^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Binary operations without any restriction? N0, there are many more. For every pair $(x,y)$ from a set $X$ we pick any value $f(x,y) \in X$, so we have $n^2$ many independent choices from $n$, so $n^{n^2}$ in my reckoning.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example, For two input 4 bit output space. 4 bit means 16 possible values. So, possible number of function is, 16. For n input, n^n^2 output.

A B O 
0 0 0 
 
0 1 0 
1 0 0 
1 1 0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).